# Set Android.mk flag through Gradle depending on build type

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I need to set a flag inside `Android.mk` file which tells to the C code whether it's debug mode or not.

```
LOCAL_MODULE := auth
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := auth.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DDEBUG_MODE=0
LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := auth.h

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The problem is that I often forget to change the value when building a release and viceversa so I'm looking forward to a way that does it automatically.

I tried changing `Android.mk` to:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DDEBUG_MODE
```

And changed the `build.gradle` to the following:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ndk {
                cFlags = " -DDEBUG_MODE=0 "
            }
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ndk {
                cFlags = " -DDEBUG_MODE=1 "
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/none']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ["src/main/libs"]
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
    return void
}
```

This was not enough, the flag is not changing depending on build type. I found few information about this and the above code is the result of what I read on the internet.
Do you have any suggestion about how to get it to work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `externalNativeBuild { ndkBuild {` within the build type. Note that the flags will be added to `APP_CFLAGS` (i.e. all modules), not `LOCAL_CFLAGS`.

build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ndkbuildtest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
                arguments "APP_STL:=gnustl_static"
                cppFlags "-std=c++11","-frtti","-fexceptions"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    cFlags "-DDEBUG_MODE=0"
                }
            }
        }
        debug {
            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    cFlags "-DDEBUG_MODE=1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "Android.mk"
        }
    }
}
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := native-lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

native-lib.cpp:

```cpp
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

#if DEBUG_MODE
#error "Debug mode enabled!
#endif

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_ndkbuildtest_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Flag value is still always 0 (not set). However I cannot see any ndk build process neither upon gradle resync nor changing build type

Comment: Where and how are you testing the value of the flag? Note that testing `LOCAL_CFLAGS` won't work, because the flag is getting added to `APP_CFLAGS`. Checking the flag in the C code works fine for me though (I'm using version 2.3.1 of the gradle plugin).

Comment: I removed `LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DDEBUG_MODE=0` from mk file and testing in C code with `# if DEBUG_MODE` (gradle 2.3.2)

Comment: Do you perhaps have a `APP_FLAGS :=` somewhere in your Application.mk or Android.mk? I've added a more complete example that works for me with 2.3.2 (if I `gradlew assembleDebug` the `#error` triggers, and if I `gradlew assembleRelease` it doesn't).

Comment: I got it to work. The problem was gradle sourceSets attribute which made the project to compile with old native precopiled libraries (the ones that I've been usually compiling though terminal). Removing the gradle attribute solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in you Application.mk file with just these few lines.

```
## DEBUG MODE
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a  #Add your target ABI's or change, it's up to you.
APP_CFLAGS += -UNDEBUG -O0 -g -ggdb 
APP_OPTIM := debug
APP_CPPFLAGS += -DDMZ_DEBUG=1
```

Comment: Please explain what the code actually does otherwise it's not clear how to integrate it with the rest of the code

Comment: Release mode is the default, and generates highly optimized binaries. Debug mode generates unoptimized binaries that are much easier to debug. When you add APP_OPTIM := debug line, it generates source as debuggable, and run all debug lines. Read APP_OPTIM section: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html .

Comment: This does not solve the problem, I still have to change APP_OPTIM value each time I build Android project in release or debug. I need a way to reflect Android project build type into mk files and the only way is through gradle (maybe using tasks?)